# Hibernate Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting started with Hibernate and have encountered a problem, namely the Exception:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: at.test.Package column: lat
```

in my TestProject i have the classes (simplified):

```
Package
-Address a
-int weight

Storage
-Location l
-int capacity

Address
-Location l
-street
-City

Location
-double lat
-double lon
```

Package and Storage are Entities, they fullfill all requirements (Serializable, default constructor...)

the members of the types Address and Location are Embedded, the classes are Embeddable.

so Storage contains and Embedded Location

Package contains an Embedded Address which contains an Embedded Location

Where exactly does hibernate find a duplicate mapping for lat in the Package class?

many thanks for hints and help!

Comment: Are there inheritance relations between those classes ?

Comment: Storage contains a List of Package, OneToMany relationship, no other relation between the classes

Comment: I think at this stage, you should copy/paste the actual classes with JPA mapping. It's hard to get anything from a simplified view.

Comment: solved it, i dont know why but attribute overriding for lat and lon in warehouse-location and Address-Location did it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this annotation in Package

@Embedded
private Address a= null;